# How to setup a local proxy server for testing a program?

Tags: networking, windows-10, mac, proxy

I have a program/SDK that should also work behind a proxy with username and password. I am not sure how to setup a local proxy so that I can route all the requests through the proxy.

I am on Mac and Windows 10 both and have tried with Charles Proxy, Squid etc, but probably I am not setting it up correctly.

I need to proxy HTTP, HTTPS and SOCKS connections through it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setup [pfSense](https://pfsense.org/) either in virtual machine or set it up on any spare computer ([requirements](http://www.firewallhardware.it/en/pfsense_selection_and_sizing.html) are very low) and follow official documentation how to [setup transparent proxy](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Setup_Squid_as_a_Transparent_Proxy). When you done,

1. Set up users who allowed to use proxy in Services > Proxy > Users
2. Disable Transparent HTTP proxy in Services > Proxy > General
3. Select LOCAL Authentication method in Services > Proxy >
   Authentication
4. Disable in firewall outgoing connections to ports 80,443
   (if you really want to create corporate production setup)

To drive workstations over proxy with authentication you either need to setup [WPAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Auto-Discovery_Protocol) (but you would need to setup first any simple web server (can be added as package in `pfSense`)) or manually on each workstation in
`control panel/internet options` on the tab `Connections` hit button <kbd>LAN settings</kbd> and tick checkbox `Use a proxy server for your LAN` in `Proxy server` section. (Use IP of `pfSense` and port `3128`). This network settings would be applied to the whole system.

If you would go with [WPAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Auto-Discovery_Protocol) then on the same tab
`Connections` in `control panel/internet options` leave all check boxes empty except `Automatically detect settings`. (If you have a lot of computers then it would be better to setup [WPAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Auto-Discovery_Protocol) address in DHCP option 252 on `pfSense` this way all workstation will pick all settings automatically)

In `firefox` (in Options->Adavanced->network->Connection Settings) you can choose either
`Use system proxy settings` (it will pick settings described above) or you may set protocols that should go over proxy with authorization in `Manual proxy configuration`